# In this case, how to save data more efficiently and conveniently?

Tags: c, algorithm

I am measuring the latency of some operations.
There are many scenarios here.
The delay of each scene is roughly distributed in a small interval.  For each scenario, I need to measure 500,000 times. Finally I want to output the delay value and its corresponding number of times.

My initial implementation was:

```
#define range 1000
int rec_array[range];

for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
  int latency = measure_latency();
  rec_array[latency]++;
}
for (int i = 0; i < range; i++) {
  printf("%d %d\n", i, rec_array[i]);
}
```

But this approach was fine at first, but as the number of scenes grew, it became problematic.

1. The delay measured in each scene is concentrated in a small interval. So for most of the data in the rec_array array is 0.
2. Since each scene is different, the delay value is also different. Some delays are concentrated around 500, and I need to create an array with a length greater than 500. But some are concentrated around 5000, and I need to create an array with a length greater than 5000.
3. Due to the large number of scenes, I created too many arrays. For example I have ten scenes and I need to create ten rec_arrays. And I also set them to be different lengths.

Is there any efficient and convenient strategy? Since I am using C language, templates like vector cannot be used.

I considered linked lists. However, considering that the interval of the delay value distribution is uncertain, and how many certain delay values ​​are uncertain, and when the same delay occurs, the timing value needs to be increased. It also doesn't seem very convenient.

I'm sorry, I just went out. Thank you for your help. I read the comments carefully. Here are some of my answers.

1. These data are mainly used to draw pictures,For example, this one below.
2. The comment area says that data seems small. The main reason why I thought about this problem is that according to the picture, only a few arrays are used each time, and the vast majority are 0. And there are many scenarios where I need to generate an array for each. I have referred to an open source implementation.
3. According to the comments, it seems that using arrays directly is a good solution, considering fast access.  Thanks veru much!

[image]

Comment: Do you really need _all_ the individual latency occurences? Commonly you define "buckets" (like 0, 1 to 10, 11 to 30, 30 to 100, ...) and count only in the buckets. This will greatly reduce the number of counters.

Comment: Honestly, @thebusybee, how is 500'000 problematically many? Assuming an `int` (which should be an `unsigned int` here) is 32 bit, that's not even 2 MB of RAM. Practically nothing. But Gerrie doesn't even keep all 500000 results around. Only 1000 counters! That's not even 4 kB of ram.

Comment: @MarcusMüller The OP tells that the size is the issue. We don't know anything about the system the software runs on...

Comment: @thebusybee yes, but the solution is to fix where they store the array, not to reduce its size!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Let's see what the OP adds to the question to clarify the issue. ;-)

Comment: What do you do with the latencies after you have stored them? Some summary statistics such as mean and standard deviation do not require the latencies to be stored, just a few sums (O(1) storage).

Comment: You should never consider linked lists for algortihms that require searching (except as secondary storage to resolve hash table collisions, etc.)

Comment: @IanAbbott your words are a balm to my developer soul. I really don't know why linked lists take such a prominent role in education still. They're almost always a bad idea, and while simple enough to explain on two slides, that should be it, not exactly what a student should tell you first when being asked what they've learned in their "intro to C" or "intro to data structures" lecture.

Comment: I have made some clarifications. Thank you all very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linked list is probably (and almost always) the least efficient way to store things – both slow as hell, and memory inefficient, since your values use less storage than your pointers. *Linked lists are very rarely a good solution for anything that actually stores significant data.* The only reason they're so prevalent is that C still has no proper containers, and they're easy wheels to
reinvent for every single C program you write.

```
#define range 1000
int rec_array[range];
```

So you're (probably! This depends on your compiler and *where* you write `int rec_array[range];`) storing `rec_array` on the stack, and it's large. (Actually, 4000 Bytes is not "large" by any modern computer's means, but still.) You should not be doing that; instead, this should be heap allocated, once, at initialization.

The solution is to allocate it:

```
/* SPDX-License-Identifier: LGPL-2.1+ */
/* Copyright Marcus Müller and others */

#include <stdlib.h>
#define N_RUNS 500000

/*
 * Call as
 *   program maximum_latency
 */

unsigned int *run_benchmark(struct task_t task, unsigned int *latencies,
                            unsigned int *max_latency) {
  for (unsigned int run = 0; run < N_RUNS; ++run) {
    unsigned int latency = measure_latency();
    if (latency >= *max_latency) {
      latency = *max_latency - 1;
      /*
       * alternatively: use realloc to increase the size of the `latencies`,
       * and update max_latency as well; that's basically what C++ std::vector
       * does
       */
      (latencies[latency])++;
    }
  }
  return latencies;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  // check argument
  if (argc != 2) {
    exit(127);
  }

  int maximum_latency_raw = atoi(argv[1]);
  if (maximum_latency_raw <= 0) {
    exit(126);
  }
  unsigned int maximum_latency = maximum_latency_raw;

  /*
   * note that the length does no longer have to be a constant
   * if you're using calloc/malloc.
   */
  unsigned int *latency_counters =
      (unsigned int *)calloc(maximum_latency, sizeof(unsigned int));

  for (; /* benchmark task in benchmark_tasks */;) {
    run_benchmark(task, latency_counters, &maximum_latency);
    print_benchmark_result(latency_counters, maximum_latency);

    // clear our counters after each run!
    memset(latency_counters, 0, maximum_latency * sizeof(unsigned int));
  }
}

void print_benchmark_result(unsigned int *array, unsigned int length) {
  for (unsigned int index = 0; index < length; ++index) {
    printf("%d %d\n", i, rec_array[i]);
  }
  puts("============================\n");
}
```

Note especially the "alternatively: realloc" comment in the middle: `realloc` allows you to increase the size of your array:

```
unsigned int *run_benchmark(struct task_t task, unsigned int *latencies,
                            unsigned int *max_latency) {
  for (unsigned int run = 0; run < N_RUNS; ++run) {
    unsigned int latency = measure_latency();
    if (latency >= *max_latency) {
      // double the size!
      latencies = (unsigned int *)realloc(latencies, (*max_latency) * 2 *
                                                         sizeof(unsigned int));

      // realloc doesn't zero out the extension, so we need to do that
      // ourselves.

      memset(latencies +  (*max_latency), 0, (*max_latency)*sizeof(unsigned int);
      (*max_latency) *= 2;
      (latencies[latency])++;
    }
  }
  return latencies;
}
```

This way, your array grows when you need it to!

Answer (score 1):

how about using a Hash table so we would only save the latency used and maybe the keys in the Hash table can be ranges while the values of said keys be the actual latency?

Comment: In general, a hash table would be a fine approach. Here, however, we're talking about not even a full 4kB page of memory. The approach of having one array in which we store our counters is significantly more efficient than growing a hashmap on the go, especially since there's probably a range that's very densely populated.

Comment: oh, and re: "hash" table: note that "hashing integers that come in probably somewhat discrete-normally distributed" is a bit of a large word for "using the last couple bits of the value as bin index as provably optimal bin assignment" ;)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Population density shouldn't matter for a good hash function. Only the number of key values in the data set and the size of the hash table should matter.

Comment: @IanAbbott au contraire! If I have say, 10 million possible values, of which I only "hit" say 1000 (your density is "sparse"), then a hash table makes sense, is space and time efficient. However, if you have 1000 possible values, and you hit 900 of them, especially in a compact range, than a hash table saves no space, and is slower than the direct addressing of an array indexed by the value itself.

Comment: @MarcusMüller That's all well and good if you know the range of values in advance, and can discard the outliers.

Comment: and: "good hash function": As said, "the last couple of bits of the value" is a "good hash function" for something that is concentrated (as e.g., but not only, normally-distributed random variables), as that leads to a uniformly-as-a-priori-possible bin utilization

Comment: @IanAbbott that's the thing, we do have domain knowledge here about the possible latencies (a benchmark that takes a day is not valid). OP can sensibly bound maximum latency to a relatively small value, and since they're running "large" experiments (as in: many more trials than possible latency values), at least *once* they'd have to allocate a large data structure, no matter whether they do it for a hash table with many different values, or for the full array. So, better do it up front. The sizes we're operating in suggest that you can *always* use the time advantage of the array approach.

Comment: @IanAbbott another thing: the hash table has to reallocate when the number of different values grows, just as well! Typically (not always, but it's what I remember from multiple implementations), you double your size once you reach a regrowth threshold. The very very same can be done with the array – see my answer's in-code "alternatively: realloc here!" comment. I don't have a CS proof at hand, but I think doubling the size when needed is probably pretty optimal when you have to assume that values are uniformly distributed (as after a good hash function) over the range of values (hashes).

Answer (score 1):

Just sacrifice some precision in your latencies like 0-15, 16-31, 32-47 ... etc. Now your array will be 16x smaller.

Allocate all latency counter arrays for all scenes in one go

```
unsigned int *latency_div16_counter = (unsigned int *)calloc((MAX_LATENCY >> 4) * NUM_OF_SCENES, sizeof(unsigned int));
```

Clamp the values to the max latency, div 16 and store

```
for (int scene = 0; scene < NUM_OF_SCENES; scene++) {
for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
  int latency = measure_latency();
  if(latency >= MAX_LATENCY) latency = MAX_LATENCY - 1;
  latency = latency >> 4; // int div 16
  latency_div16_counter[(scene * MAX_LATENCY) + latency]++;
}
}
```

Adjust the data (mul 16) before displaying it

```
for (int scene = 0; scene < NUM_OF_SCENES; scene++) {
for (int i = 0; i < (MAX_LATENCY >> 4); i++) {
  printf("Scene %d Latency %d Total %d\n", scene, i * 16, latency_div16_counter[i]);
}
}
```